# Why is TensorFlow predicting all 0's or all 1's after training?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, tensorflow

So my problem is that I am running through the beginner level code in the TensorFlow tutorial and have modified it for my needs but when I make it `print sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test})` it used to always print out a 1.0, now it's always guessing 0's and printing out an ~93% accuracy. When I use `tf.argmin(y,1), tf.argmin(y_,1)`, it guesses all 1's and produces an ~7% accuracy rate. Add up the two and it equals 100%. I don't get how `tf.argmin` guesses 1's and `tf.argmax` guesses 0's. Obviously something is wrong with the code. Please have a look and let me know what I can do to fix this issue. I think that the code is going wrong during the training, but I could be wrong.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

data = genfromtxt('cs-training.csv',delimiter=',')  # Training data
test_data = genfromtxt('cs-test.csv',delimiter=',')  # Test data

x_train = []
for i in data:
    x_train.append(i[1:])
x_train = np.array(x_train)

y_train = []
for i in data:
    if i[0] == 0:
        y_train.append([1., i[0]])
    else:
        y_train.append([0., i[0]])
y_train = np.array(y_train)

where_are_NaNs = isnan(x_train)
x_train[where_are_NaNs] = 0

x_test = []
for i in test_data:
    x_test.append(i[1:])
x_test = np.array(x_test)

y_test = []
for i in test_data:
    if i[0] == 0:
        y_test.append([1., i[0]])
    else:
        y_test.append([0., i[0]])
y_test = np.array(y_test)

where_are_NaNs = isnan(x_test)
x_test[where_are_NaNs] = 0

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,2]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

y_ = tf.placeholder("float", [None,2])

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

print "...Training..."

g = 0
for i in range(len(x_train)):

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: [x_train[g]], y_: [y_train[g]]})

    g += 1
```

At this point, if I make it `print [x_train[g]]` and `print [y_train[g]]`, this is what the results look like.

```
[array([  7.66126609e-01,   4.50000000e+01,   2.00000000e+00,
     8.02982129e-01,   9.12000000e+03,   1.30000000e+01,
     0.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
     2.00000000e+00])]

[array([ 0.,  1.])]
```

Ok, let's carry on then.

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

print sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test})
0.929209
```

This percentage does not shift. It's guessing all zeros regardless of the onehot that I created for the 2 classes (1 or 0).

Here's a look at the data-

```
print x_train[:10]

[[  7.66126609e-01   4.50000000e+01   2.00000000e+00   8.02982129e-01
9.12000000e+03   1.30000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   6.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00]
 [  9.57151019e-01   4.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   1.21876201e-01
2.60000000e+03   4.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]
 [  6.58180140e-01   3.80000000e+01   1.00000000e+00   8.51133750e-02
3.04200000e+03   2.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.33809776e-01   3.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   3.60496820e-02
3.30000000e+03   5.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  9.07239400e-01   4.90000000e+01   1.00000000e+00   2.49256950e-02
6.35880000e+04   7.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.13178682e-01   7.40000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   3.75606969e-01
3.50000000e+03   3.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]
 [  3.05682465e-01   5.70000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   5.71000000e+03
0.00000000e+00   8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  7.54463648e-01   3.90000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   2.09940017e-01
3.50000000e+03   8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.16950644e-01   2.70000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   4.60000000e+01
0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.89169052e-01   5.70000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   6.06290901e-01
2.36840000e+04   9.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00]]

print y_train[:10]

[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]]

print x_test[:20]

[[  4.83539240e-02   4.40000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   3.02297622e-01
7.48500000e+03   1.10000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00]
 [  9.10224439e-01   4.20000000e+01   5.00000000e+00   1.72900000e+03
0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.92682927e-01   5.80000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   3.66480079e-01
3.03600000e+03   7.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]
 [  3.11547538e-01   3.30000000e+01   1.00000000e+00   3.55431993e-01
4.67500000e+03   1.10000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   7.20000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   2.16630600e-03
6.00000000e+03   9.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.79217052e-01   4.50000000e+01   1.00000000e+00   4.89921122e-01
6.84500000e+03   8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   7.80000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  9.10363487e-01   2.80000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   4.99451497e-01
6.38000000e+03   8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  6.36595797e-01   4.40000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   7.85457163e-01
4.16600000e+03   6.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.41549211e-01   2.60000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   2.68407434e-01
4.25000000e+03   4.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  4.14101100e-03   7.80000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   2.26362500e-03
5.74200000e+03   7.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  9.99999900e-01   6.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   1.20000000e+02
0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  6.28525944e-01   4.70000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   1.13100000e+03
0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00]
 [  4.02283095e-01   6.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   3.79442065e-01
8.63800000e+03   1.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  5.70997900e-03   8.10000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   2.17382000e-04
2.30000000e+04   4.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  4.71171849e-01   5.10000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   1.53700000e+03
0.00000000e+00   1.40000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.42395210e-02   8.20000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   7.40466500e-03
2.70000000e+03   1.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  4.67455800e-02   3.70000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   1.48010090e-02
9.12000000e+03   8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+00]
 [  9.99999900e-01   4.70000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   3.54604127e-01
1.10000000e+04   1.10000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00]
 [  8.96417860e-02   2.70000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   8.14664000e-03
5.40000000e+03   6.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]

print y_test[:20]
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]]
```

Comment: Do you always test on the same datasets? if you shuffle them, is the result still 1.0?

Comment: Yep it's still a 1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:  The way the sample code above posted computes the cross-entropy is not numerically robust.  Use `tf.nn.cross_entropy_with_logits` instead.**

(in response to v1 of the question, which has changed):  I'm worried that your training is not actually getting run to completion or working, based upon the `nan`s in your x_train data that you showed.  I'd suggest first fixing that - and identifying why they showed up and fixing that bug, and seeing if you also have `nan`s in your test set.  Might be helpful to show x_test and y_test also.

Finally, I believe there's a bug in the way `y_` is handled in relation to x.  The code is written as if `y_` is a one-hot matrix, but when you show `y_train[:10]`, it only has 10 elements, not `10*num_classes` categories.  I suspect a bug there.  When you argmax it on axis 1, you're always going to get a vector full of zeros (because there's only one element on that axis, so of course it's the maximum element).  Combine that with a bug producing always-zero output on the estimate, and you're always producing a "correct" answer. :)

**Update for revised version**
In the changed version, if you run it and print out W at the end of every execution by changing your code to look like this:

```
 _, w_out, b_out = sess.run([train_step, W, b], feed_dict={x: [x_train[g]], y_: [y_train[g]]})
```

you'll observe that W is full of `nan`s.  To debug this, you can either stare a lot at your code to see if there's a mathematical problem you can spot, or you can instrument back through the pipeline to see where they show up.  Let's try that.  First, what's the `cross_entropy`?  (add `cross_entropy` to the list of things in the `run` statement and print it out)

```
Cross entropy:  inf
```

Great!  So.. why?  Well, one answer is that when:

```
y = [0, 1]
tf.log(y) = [-inf, 0]
```

This is a valid possible output for y, but one that your computation of the cross-entropy is not robust to.  You could either manually add some epsilons to avoid the corner cases, or use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` to do it for you.  I recommend the latter:

```
yprime = tf.matmul(x,W)+b
y = tf.nn.softmax(yprime)
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(yprime, y_)
```

I don't guarantee that your model will work, but this should fix your current NaN problem.

Comment: Could you please show how you would adjust the code to produce a normal result? I'll get rid of all of the rows with nan's quickly for now (to save time).

Comment: I change the argmax to 0, 0 and got a 0% accuracy. Changed it to 0, 1 and got a 100% accuracy. Changed it to 1, 0 and got a 0% accuracy. I don't know if that helps you understand the problem any more, but I figured I would give you the information.

Comment: I keep coming back to what you said and I've been trying to get this to work for 2 entire days. Can you please come back to this and write out code that will do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you so much for this brilliant response. I would have had to search through the entire Github repo to MAYBE learn how to program this. It's actually working now :)

Comment: I clicked this as the answer at first, but I'm realizing now that it's still not solving the issue. It has a lower percentage of accuracy with the beginner part of the tutorial (the code I mentioned above) because, I assume, that it's not guessing all 0's (which isn't a bad thing). As I see when neural networks get trained and retrained, they adjust the accuracy. That's not what's happening here. Thank you for the wonderful advice and code, but it's still not working for me.

Comment: You know what. This is probably the right answer; it's probably just the data that I'm working with that's just not compatible with deep learning. I've done everything. It should either predict a 1 or a 0, but it predicts all 0's or all 1's (when I train the data on half 1's and half 0's). I've learned so much about TensorFlow by now and appreciate the help but I just don't think that there's any more options. The data is too noisy, even after I add another 60 features to it. I'm not calling it a failure, but it's just not working out.

Comment: It's not about deep learning - it's probably about using too simple a model.  You may need another layer to represent the underlying function of the data.  See http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-03-NN-Manifolds-Topology/ for example.  There may also be other bugs.  Maybe a cleaned up example with a second question now that you've got it running and predicting things?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271493/what-is-going-wrong-with-the-training-and-predictions-using-tensorflow